# SLACK - read the last image in a channel - get it's URL and send it to an API via a Slack APP

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to upload a file to a channel, and then type `/mycommand` which would then read the slack url of the image that was uploaded into the channel and then send that as a argument to `/mycommand [url]`

I have managed to get my APP working so that I can invoke `/mycommand [url]` but I need help to figure out how to automate the reading of the last uploaded file vs. having to add the argument url to /mycommand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible. A Slack app can be triggered with a slash command and then indeed fetch the URL of the last shared file of the current channel and then do something with that. But you can not automatically add that URL to a slash command.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken - Thank you - I have managed to get the /mycommand [url] piece working as a manual typed entry. May I ask if you know how I would be able to get the URL of the last shared file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the URL of the latest shared file you can call the API method [conversations.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.history) for the current channel. It will return the list of all message incl. uploaded filed. From that you can filter out file uploads and sort by date to get the URL.

Note that slash commands have a 3 seconds time limit, so you probably want to implement the processing of the channel history asynchronously.